# Enviar e-mail pelo R

Tags: r, email

Estou tentando enviar e-mails pelo R com o pacote `mailR`. Coloquei as informações que o pacote solicita, mas testando com e-mails diferentes, acabo recebendo o mesmo erro.

Meu código:

```
library(mailR)

send.mail(from = "meuemail@hotmail.com",
          to = "meuemail@gmail.com",
          subject = "E-mail teste",
          body = "Este e-mail foi enviado pelo R.",
          smtp = list(host.name = "SMTP.office365.com", port = 587, 
                      user.name = "meuemail@hotmail.com",            
                      passwd = "minhasenha", ssl = TRUE), 
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Erro que está retornando:

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : SMTP.office365.com:465
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at RJavaTools.invokNULL
eMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: SMTP.office365.com, 465; timeout 60000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2053)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:310)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:215)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2019)
    ... 13 more
Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : SMTP.office365.com:465
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, eu também tentei fazer isso semana passada, com esse pacote, e não consegui (um problema específico do gmail, é que ele não deixa app's de terceiros enviar ou receber e-mail. Os outros e-mails também devem ter uma restrição parecida com essa). Normalmente esses problemas que você está enfrentando é devido a segurança imposta pelo servidor do e-mail.
Além desse pacote, eu tentei outros 5 e nenhum funcionou de uma maneira "natural", isto é, sem precisar mudar configuração do e-mail.

O único que deu certo, foi o `gmailr`. Eu testaria esse.
Você pode seguir os passos [desse link](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3398701/how-to-send-email-from-r-and-gmail.html)

Comment: Obrigado! O tutorial funcionou perfeitamente.